# Why does ffmpeg h264 decoder stop decoding when certain type of packets are coming in the input stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I used av_read_frame to get the AVPacket from encoded h264 file. But when this packet (00 00 01 05 94 5a 33 e7 4d 6b d7 ad 13 86 ff 47 83 93 31 f1 e3 0a) is in the input stream (h264 video) ffmpeg decoder stops decoding frames for any subsequent AVPackets.
But if I skip this packet to provide to the decoder the next AVPackets decode just fine. What is wrong with this packet? Or what is wrong with the ffmpeg decoder?

Below is the test stream for reference.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rHCfG4csA3rB4LSgErEBn1F3WfI5nUVr

Comment: If you run ffmpeg with `-v debug` it might give some more clues. Maybe you can paste the log to some pastebin etc and maybe even upload your test file somewhere?

Comment: +Do you check packet type (A/V/Other) before supplying this to the correct decoder?

Comment: Yes I check and only if it is video I provide it to the decoder. Infact I removed this packet from the input file and then my test application decodes the whole file just fine. But only if this packet is in the file the test application stops decoding at this packet even though any further packets are provided to the decoder.

Comment: I looked more into what type of packet it is to find out that it is an IDR packet but the ffmpeg decoder returns error saying its invalid data/packet and after that the ffmpeg decoder does not decode any further packets.

Comment: It’s customary on Stack Overflow to post an answer your own question if you solve your problem. Posting an answer rather than a comment makes your experience available to others.